# Latest compiler versions and GLIBC_2.32 dependency

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, clang, c++17

- When I compile my library with **GCC 11** or **Clang 12** I get a GLIBC_2.32 dependency.
- When I compile the same library with the same arguments but with older version compilers (**GCC 10**, **Clang 11**) I don't get the GLIBC_2.32 dependency.

Is there a way to get rid of this dependency on newer versions of compilers?

```
readelf -s mylib.so | grep GLIBC                                        
 4: 00000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND [...]@GLIBC_2.1.3 (2)
 5: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND sn[...]@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
 6: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND strlen@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
 7: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND getcwd@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
 8: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dlopen@GLIBC_2.1 (4)
 9: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND strcmp@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
10: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dlsym@GLIBC_2.0 (5)
11: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND st[...]@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
12: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND fopen@GLIBC_2.1 (6)
13: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND fgets@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
14: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND fclose@GLIBC_2.1 (6)
15: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND isspace@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
16: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memchr@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
17: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
18: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND puts@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
19: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND bcmp@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
20: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __[...]@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
21: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND strtol@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
22: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND abort@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
23: 00000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _[...]@GLIBC_2.32 (7)  << WHAT IS THIS?
24: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND sprintf@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
25: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND strncmp@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
26: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gettext@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
27: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __[...]@GLIBC_2.4 (8)
28: 00000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND pt[...]@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
29: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND realloc@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
30: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memset@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
31: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND read@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
32: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memcmp@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
34: 00000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND pt[...]@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
35: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND fputc@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
36: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND fputs@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
37: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memcpy@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
38: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
39: 00000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND stderr@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
40: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND ioctl@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
41: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND fwrite@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
42: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND close@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
43: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND open@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
44: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND syscall@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
45: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND memmove@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
46: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND free@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
47: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _[...]@GLIBC_2.3 (10)
```

Comment: We don't have enough information to respond. Most likely the newer compilers are using more compliant or fixed methods in the libc. FWIW you have a dependency on 2.4 on line 27

Comment: gcc-10.3.0 (and it's results) can also depend on glibc-2.32, and gcc-11.2.0 : glibc-2.33 . The older versions often used only older objects from glibc, example 2.0 .... 2.18 .